# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when assigning a value from an array to a UILabel

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uilabel

This is the code in my first ViewController

```
FirstViewController.

@IBOutletweakvar textField: UITextField!

array = [String]()

...

array.append(textField.text!)

...

overridefunc prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

let secondScene = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController

secondScene.inputArray = inputArray
```

This is the code in my second ViewController.

```
SecondViewController

@IBOutletweakvar label: UILabel!

array = [String]()

...

print(array) // getting the value that was input by the user

someLabel.text = array[0]  // on this line I am getting there error about getting nil
```

So i am inputing values to an array from textFields in the first scene and i am trying to have everything that was input by the user on the first scene print to a label in the second scene. When i try to pull the value from the array and assign it to the Label.text it gives me the error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I really have no clue why this is happening.

Comment: What is displayed in the `print(array)`? Is the `someLabel.text = array[0]` happening right after? Have you tried putting a literal string instead `array[0]`?

Comment: I think I found it. The label must not have been correctly connected to the ViewController. I got the same error when i tried using a literal string. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your abbreviated code correctly, you are populating `array` in `FirstViewController`, but pass `inputArray`.

And in `SecondViewController` you don't read `inputArray`, but `array`

You need to populate, pass and read the same array.